# Iterate through the letters of the alphabet in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'd like to write a program that iterates through the letters in the alphabet as symbols and does something with them.  I'd like it to be roughly equivalent to this C code:

```c
for(char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
{
    printf("The letter is %c\n", letter);
}
```

I really have no idea how to do this in Racket. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to iterate over lowercase English alphabet letters, here's one way to do it:

```
(define alphabet (string->list "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))

(for ([letter alphabet])
  (displayln letter))
```

You can do a lot more with `for` loops though. For example,

```
(for/list ([let alphabet] [r-let (reverse alphabet)])
  (list let r-let))
```

produces a list of letters paired with letters going the other direction. Although that's actually better expressed as a map: `(map list alphabet (reverse alphabet))`.

Also, [SRFI-14](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-14.html) provides more operations over sets of characters if you need more.

Edit: Originally, I did something with `char->integer`, `integer->char`, and `range` but what I have now is simpler.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that there's no way to do it without explicitly defining the entire alphabet?

Comment: Racket isn't C++ so there is no punning on characters vs. integers. If you really really wanted to, you could write a loop that starts at `(char->integer #\a)` and ends at `(char->integer #\z)` but there's no good reason to program that way in Racket. Note that in C++ if you wanted to iterate over any other set of characters you would have to do something like that too.

Comment: My original answer was overly complicated. I updated it to use `string->list` instead. You could also directly iterate on the string like `(for ([letter "abc..."]) (displayln letter))`.

Answer (score 8):

Just so that one of the answers shows the literal translation approach:

```
#lang racket
(for ([letter (in-range (char->integer #\a)
                        (add1 (char->integer #\z)))])
  (printf "The letter is ~a\n" (integer->char letter)))
```

Racket doesn't support the implicit punning between characters and integers that C permits: unlike in C, a Racket value's type is intrinsic rather than external to the value itself.  The `char->integer` and `integer->char` functions do the explicit translations between those types.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [sequence](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html) constructor that lets you iterate over a character range without needing to make an intermediate string or list or messing with `char->integer` and `integer->char` directly (It does that bit for you):

```lisp
; Contract: (-> char? char? sequence?)
(define (in-char-range start end)
  (make-do-sequence
   (lambda ()
     (values
      integer->char ; pos->element
      #f ; early-next-pos
      (if (char<=? start end) ; next-pos
          add1
          sub1)
      (char->integer start) ; initial position
      #f ; continue-with-pos?
      #f ; continue-with-val?
      (lambda (pos val) (not (char=? val end))))))) ; continue-after-pos+val?

(for ([ch (in-char-range #\a #\z)])
  (printf "The letter is ~A~%" ch))
; The letter is a
; The letter is b
; ...
; The letter is z
```

Also supports going in descending order:

```lisp
(for ([ch (in-char-range #\z #\a)])
  (printf "The letter is ~A~%" ch))
```

Comment: Old, old question, but I don't really like either existing answer.